# CSS layout in percent shows smaller right margin in Firefox

Tags: html, css, layout

I am encountering a little challenge while scripting some css; indeed, the right margin appears smaller than the left one, while both are set up at 5%!

Using Firefox 35.0.1

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: #fff;
}
#main-content {
  float: left;
  width: 57%;
  background: #a7cbd3;
  margin-left: 5%;
  min-height: 777px;
}
#side {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  background: #0081a9;
  margin-right: 5%;
  min-height: 777px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">Main content</div>
<div id="side">Side</div>
```

May I ask your advice(s)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset default `body` margin to prevent content overflow.

```
body {
  margin: 5% 0 0; /* added margin-top 5% as previous rule */
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5% 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
#main-content {
  float: left;
  width: 57%;
  background: #a7cbd3;
  margin-left: 5%;
  min-height: 777px;
}
#side {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  background: #0081a9;
  margin-right: 5%;
  min-height: 777px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-content">Main content</div>
  <div id="side">Side</div>
</body>

</html>
```